# Converting windows sockets to .NET

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a pretty simple sockets connection that seems to work under WinSock 2.0 but not at all under .NET.  The only thing I know is one works and the other does not at all, but I'm not sure how to debug it.

Windows sockets version:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK ConnectDialogProc (HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    SOCKET ConnectMe;
    int Status, cRemoteAddr;
    LRESULT ItemData;
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr, RemoteAddr;
    CERDISPINFO Info;
    BOOL fReuseAddr = TRUE;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG :
        memset (&SockAddr, 0, sizeof(SockAddr));
        SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        SockAddr.sin_port = htons(987);
        SockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        ConnectMe = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        setsockopt (ConnectMe, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&fReuseAddr, sizeof(fReuseAddr));
        bind (ConnectMe, (SOCKADDR *)&SockAddr, sizeof(SockAddr));
        WSAAsyncSelect (ConnectMe, hwndDlg, WM_CONNECT_ME, FD_READ);
        SetWindowLong (hwndDlg, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)ConnectMe);
        return TRUE;
    case WM_CONNECT_ME :
        ConnectMe = (SOCKET)wParam;
        cRemoteAddr = sizeof(RemoteAddr);
        Status = recvfrom (ConnectMe, (char*)&Info, sizeof(Info), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&RemoteAddr, &cRemoteAddr);
        if (Status != SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
            // Convert ip addr to host order
            ItemData = ntohl(RemoteAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

And here is the roughly equivalent .NET version:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Unspecified);

    SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(socketEventArg_Completed);

    socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 987);
    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 987));
    socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
}

void socketEventArg_Completed(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    Boolean b = true;
}
```

The .NET version never hits the 'Boolean b = true' breakpoint while the C++ WinSocks one reports there is a device within a second or so, every time.  I even tried reversing the byte order in the port in the .NET version to 56067 but it didn't work either.  What am I missing?  It looks like .NET doesn't accept the remote endpoint of 0.0.0.0...

Comment: You poor unfortunate soul. Are you in a position where you have to connect to a legacy system? Or are you able to modify both endpoints of your socket communication? If the latter, you might want to take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) as an alternative to this pain.

Comment: To add to Timothy Shields comment. If you are able to modify both endpoints checkout http://www.networkcomms.net. Disclaimer: I'm a developer for this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
Form1()
{
    UdpClient client = new UdpClient(987);
    client.BeginReceive(UDPClient_Callback, client);
}

void UDPClient_Callback(IAsyncResult result)
{

}
```

Thanks guys for looking!